# HTACCESS ModRewrite to hide extra URL attributes

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an URL looking like this: `http://localhost/blog/web-design-for-speed/post/?pid=CMATWA6YTXT6LSKYVXE3` which already uses ModRewrite conditions:

```
# rewrite URL from ?url=slug to /slug
RewriteEngine on
# BaseRewrite /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
# redirect www to non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The code above does change the ?url= to blog/ but, I'm still left with the ?pid. My question is, is it possible to hide the ?pid but, still have access to it through $_GET using PHP?

Comment: You can get that pid to you just need to write another ajax which matches your pid and get the value of that as `$2` in .htaccess

Comment: I came to the conclusion that, if such rewrite has to be made, it has more to do with bad concept. Using modrewrite would not make the pid prettier anyhow..

Answer (score 0):

The PID still needs to be passed to the server even when rewrite rules are being used, the best thing you could achieve would be to have the PID appear in the URL as part of the virtual directory structure, I have achieved this using the following...

.htaccess

```
## No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects


RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

In your code all you have to do is get the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` super global and parse it, explode it using `explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` and then you wind up with an array with each element in the URL having its own array index starting from zero, you can then put anything you want into the URL and access it through the exploded array.

Comment: Could someone please explain why this answer would have been downvoted given the fact that from what I can tell I answered the question fully, and provided a documented alternative solution. I would like to know so that I can improve my answers in the future, thanks.